# When Submitting Form, getting Null in JqueryAjax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, codeigniter

I have created a form, that submits its data through Ajax. The form shows me success message but when i see Response it shows Null in 1 data field.

**Post:**

```
teacher_id    6
user_id    4
comment   MyCommentttttt
```

**Response:**

```
{"teacher_id":"6","user_id":"4","comment":null}
```

I have written the following code, it successfully send `teacher_id` & `user_id` but unable to send `comment` data. Kindly check the code and guide me what i am doing wrong here.

**View -Jquery**

```
var teacherId= $("input#teacher_id").val();
    var userId= $("input#user_id").val();
    var commentText =$("textarea#comments").val() ; 

    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/data_controller/user_comments",
            dataType: "json", 
            data: {teacher_id:teacherId, user_id: userId, comment: commentText },
            success: function(){
                    alert("success");
                },
            error: function()   {
                alert("Fail");
                }

    });
```

**Controller**

```
public function user_comments()
    {
        $teacher_id= $this->input->post('teacher_id');
        $user_id= $this->input->post('user_id');
        $comments= $this->input->post('comments');

        $data= array(
                    'teacher_id'    =>  $teacher_id,
                    'user_id'       =>  $user_id,
                    'comment'       =>  $comments,
                    'Date'          =>  date('Y-m-d')   
        );

    //  $this->load->model('comments');
    //  $this->comments->add_comments($data);

        echo json_encode($data);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send the parameter named `comment`, but in the server you're checking for `comments`. Change the below line:

```
$comments = $this->input->post('comment'); // < note the 's' is removed
```

Comment: I have spent more than 2 hours on this..How can be i so blind ! Thanks anyway :)